# Interference in thin films and fringes formed

Tags: optics

Let suppose I need to find the thickness of a soap film on which white light in incident at some certain angle.the light refracted by it is examined and the two bright bands are focused corresponding to different wavelengths. My question is -are the two bright bands formed form the same refracted light and how can I obtain the relation between the order of the fringes ?

Comment: It was closed because it didn't matched the criteria of this app,so I added another question editing that,I still haven't got any answer

Comment: I have edited the closed question, still no one answered

Comment: No, you just re-asked the same question and seem to expect a different outcome. When closed, you are expected to edit the question to conform to the expectations of this site, not just keep asking it.

Comment: Well, perhaps the question is not suitable for this site - not all questions are.

Comment: @JonCuster no,I have edited the closed question, saw no answers and hence posted another .I am new to this app ,I really dont know how the stuff works ,I am sorry .can you tell me what to do next